# Numbers: One seventy-five

Tags: numbers

Number 175: Is it correct to say "one seventy-five" instead of "one hundred seventy-five"? Are both versions correct?

Comment: If it's a number (e.g. of a room) and not an amount, "one seven five" would be usual.

Comment: @KateBunting Not in my experience: people usually combine the last two digits.

Comment: @AntonSherwood - Are you in the USA? 'One seven five' would be quite normal in the UK.

Comment: @KateBunting We learn something every day.  Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Normally "a/one hundred [and] seventy-five".  "And" is used more in British dialects,

You might drop the "hundred" in some informal contexts where time is short. It would be understood, but it isn't the usual way to speak numbers.

> Look, I want two hundred dollars, and you're offering one-fifty, you're gonna have to do better.

(Previous mention of "two hundred dollars" provides context for understanding "one-fifty" to mean $150 and not $1.50.)

Comment: In the U.S., "a hundred seventy-five" is common.

Comment: "How much are you asking for the bike? " "one seventy five" (that were taking about a dollar amount of $175 and not $1.75 is understood from context) wouldn't be unusual at all in America.

Comment: How about "page one seventy-five"? As in "Open your book to page one seventy-five"?

Comment: Yes, that's quite common.  Page numbers are almost never fractional!  but sometimes a book's chapters have pages numbered separately (especially in technical manuals that get partial updates from time to time), so “page 1-75” could exist and the hyphen would typically not be pronounced.